# MS Access 2002 forms query/table for each row in Record source query

Tags: ms-access

i have a query as Record Source for a Form, for each row in that query there is a linked table with n rows matching that row, I want to return one field from all of the n matching rows in a listbox for each row in the query. how do i implement the filter that there should be a match between 1 field in the query and in the linked table?

Comment: Are you using a datasheet, a single form or a continuous form? With single forms, this is quite easy, but with datasheets and continuous forms, it is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the row source of a listbox to an sql string. For example:

```
SELECT ID, AText FROM Table1 WHERE ID = Forms!Form1!ID
```

How the data is stored will depend on the Bound Column and the Control Source. If you do not wish to show the matching column, in this case ID, you can set the column widths. You should set the column count to the correct number of columns.

```
Column Widths: 0;2.5
Column Count: 2
```

You will then have to requery the listbox in the current event:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
Me.List1.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: thx would have been really slow for me to figure that out. With continuous forms which is really what I need what do I do? the Current event is triggered first when you click on the current form (expect for the first row). combo boxes for instance update themselves in this case it seems without having to be handled with events, textBoxes you use Me.txtBoxName = Replace(Me.txtBoxName, ...) . In Access 2003 atleast.

Comment: As I said in my initial comment, this is not a good idea with continuous forms. in a continuous form, the current record is always the record highlighted, which means that anything that applies to the record highlighted will apply to all visible records, and this is confusing for the user. It is best to display the data using a suitable query that joins the two tables and then provide a button or such like for editing.